# Querying a Many to Many Structure for a subset of joined rows

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have a simple many to many db structure:

Table 1: `ITEM`
Columns:
`ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME`

Table 2: `Attribute`
Columns:
`ATTRIBUTE_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME`

Table 3: `ITEM_ATTRIBUTE`
`ITEM_ID, ATTRIBUTE_ID`

What I want is to "get all items that have the following x attributes".  X can be any number of attributes.

The best I've come up with is the following, but I believe there has to be a better way using joins and/or "select where in" clauses...but I can't think of it.

```
SELECT * FROM Item
WHERE Item.ITEM_ID IN
(SELECT ITEM_ATTRIBUTE.item_ID FROM ITEM_ATTRIBUTE WHERE ITEM_ATTRIBUTE.attribute_ID =1)
and Item.ITEM_ID in
(SELECT ITEM_ATTRIBUTE.item_ID FROM ITEM_ATTRIBUTE WHERE ITEM_ATTRIBUTE.attribute_ID =3);
```

I'd rather not have to add an additional "ITEM_ID in (...) for each attribute in the list.. esp if the list of attributes is 20+ long

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest populating a temporary table with the attributes that you would like to require.  Once you have this table, the query becomes much cleaner and maintainable.

```
DECLARE @Item TABLE (
    Item_Id INT,
    Item_Name VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @Attribute TABLE (
    Attribute_Id INT,
    Attribute_Name VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @Item_Attribute TABLE (
    Item_Id INT,
    Attribute_Id INT
)

INSERT INTO @Item VALUES (1, 'Widget')
INSERT INTO @Item VALUES (2, 'Woozle')

INSERT INTO @Attribute VALUES (1, 'foo')
INSERT INTO @Attribute VALUES (2, 'bar')
INSERT INTO @Attribute VALUES (3, 'baz')
INSERT INTO @Attribute VALUES (4, 'qux')

INSERT INTO @Item_Attribute VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO @Item_Attribute VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO @Item_Attribute VALUES (1, 3)
INSERT INTO @Item_Attribute VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT INTO @Item_Attribute VALUES (2, 4)

DECLARE @Required_Attribute TABLE (
    Attribute_Id INT
)

INSERT INTO @Required_Attribute VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @Required_Attribute VALUES (2)

SELECT *
FROM @Item i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM 
        @Required_Attribute ra 
        LEFT JOIN @Item_Attribute missingAttribute
            ON ra.Attribute_Id = missingAttribute.Attribute_Id
            AND missingAttribute.Item_Id = i.Item_Id
    WHERE
        missingAttribute.Attribute_Id IS NULL
)
```